# Can I use Group Policy to configure SSO for SharePoint

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, sharepoint

I am trying to set up SSO in Group policy so when users go to our SharePoint they are automatically signed in instead of having to sign in every time they go to the website. I cannot find anything useful online as far as walkthroughs. Can anyone explain to me how to do this or send me a link to a useful article?

Comment: What have you done so far? Sharepoint on premises or Sharepoint Online? Vague questions about trying to do something aren't helpful. We need as many details as you can provide.

Comment: `I cannot find anything useful online`. Not surprising, it isn't related to Group Policy.

Comment: Not a terrible question, but just heading down the wrong track. Try reframing your searches for "SharePoint single sign on" instead of looking specifically at GPOs. ;) What version of SharePoint Server is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running SharePoint Server 2013, 2016, or 2019 on-premises, you can start with the following Microsoft documentation:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/authentication-overview

It will get you started with using claims-based authentication, which can automatically log in Active Directory users using Kerberos, or you can use SAML for SSO.

Either way, you'll find that this will be configured in your SharePoint farm *and* in Active Directory (service principle names, etc) and/or in your SAML SSO provider.